# creating Method from code

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm still noob at java, only know the basics, and i'm with a little problem that i wish you could help me.

I this next piece of code that i use like 5 times in the project i'm making, and to keep the code simple i want to make it a method.

the only thing that i need to change in this piece of code is the Query, it is the only variable.

Thanks in advance. (sorry for my bad english).

```
Vector columnNames = new Vector();
Vector data = new Vector();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //
try {
  Conectar();
  String query = "Select * from Dados";
   stm = (Statement) con.createStatement();
   rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
   ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
   int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
   for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
   columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
}
while (rs.next()) {
   Vector row = new Vector(columns);
   for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
   row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
}
 data.addElement(row);
}
 rs.close();
 stm.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e);
}
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
TableColumn column;
for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
column.setMaxWidth(250);
}
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
table.setEnabled(false);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); panel.add(scrollPane); 
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(panel); //adiciona o panel à frame
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(640, 480); //define o tamanho da frame
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true); //torna a frame visivel
}
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just surround your code with

```
public void goodDescriptiveName(String query) {
    ...
}
```

and remove the line

```
String query = "Select * from Dados";
```

from your code. Then you just call it like this:

```
goodDescriptiveName("Select * from Dados");
goodDescriptiveName("Select * from Next");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean someAction(String query) {
...
rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
...
return true;
}
```

If you encounter any errors, return `false`. If you don't want to test it with true/false, just use `void` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void methodName(String query) {
    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //
    try {
      Conectar();
       stm = (Statement) con.createStatement();
       rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
       ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
       int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
       for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
       columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
       Vector row = new Vector(columns);
       for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
       row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
    }
     data.addElement(row);
    }
     rs.close();
     stm.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    TableColumn column;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    column.setMaxWidth(250);
    }
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    table.setEnabled(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); panel.add(scrollPane); 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel); //adiciona o panel à frame
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(640, 480); //define o tamanho da frame
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true); //torna a frame visivel
    } 
}
```

But i think that GUI code should be extracted elsewhere. :)

Comment: And how should i do it? do you mean a method to show the GUI?

Comment: @HugoMonteiro You can create one method for fetching data, and another one which takes that data and creates buttons/tables and other GUI elements.